# Do I need to cache such data in Redis?

Tags: caching, redis

I have a page on my website that has a list of tasks that I add myself. The list of tasks changes approximately once a week. There are only 30 tasks.

On page 2 of the request. The first request is to receive the number of tasks and the total amount of remuneration if you complete all these tasks. For example: Complete 30 tasks and get 2000 points.

```
SELECT
 COUNT(*) as `count`,
 SUM(`reward_amount`) as `sum_reward_amount`
FROM `tasks`
WHERE 1
 ".($tasks_done_ids ? 'AND `id` NOT IN('.$tasks_done_ids.')' : '')."
 AND `no_active` = '0'
```

And the second request to get the list of tasks itself:

```
SELECT
 `id`,
 `title`,
 `type`
FROM `tasks`
WHERE 1
 ".($tasks_done_ids ? 'AND `id` NOT IN('.$tasks_done_ids.')' : '')."
 AND `no_active` = '0'
ORDER BY `position` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

`$tasks_done_ids` contains the id of completed tasks (1,2,3,4) of each user.

This page has about 250-400 hits per second. And it would seem that everything works fast, the indexes are worth it, but sometimes for some reason I began to think that all this could be sent to the Redis cache to reduce the load on mysql. That is, to store there an array from the list of tasks and the amount of remuneration.

Is it worth using a cache in this case, or will it work faster with MySQL?

Comment: Can you explain WHY you would WANT another layer of software to manage something that is already less than 1 second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the fact that the data nearly doesn't change (you say once in a week or so) and on the other hand gets read 200-450 times per second makes it a perfect candidate for being cached.

Whether you should Redis or not - depends.
If you have only 30 tasks, maybe you can opt for an in-memory cache and it will access the data even faster because Redis still requires a network call to be done. Of course, if your application is distributed then synchronization of the cache can require Redis or some other centralized cache store but this is beyond the scope of the question I guess.

Whether Redis will work faster than MySQL in this case or not - again in general it should, but you should measure, there are so many things we don't know about your setup: the network, the server that serves MySQL / Redis, the other requests that MySQL serves and so on. And in addition to all the above, there are non "purely technical" arguments: Whether you have Redis at all in your setup, what are the maintenance costs of introducing Redis in case you don't have it, etc.
And the most important is whether you have an actual performance issue that you would like/need to solve here :)

So bottom line, strictly technically speaking - I believe it might make sense to introduce cache here but there are too many concerns that you should take into consideration before you actually decide - so its nearly impossible to provide a good answer to this question in the format of SO.